# cant change elements value in cubic matrix

Tags: python, arrays

i have a matrix

```
Matrix = [[[]] * 5 for i in range(5)]
```

i'm trying to change the inner element with the following code, but somewhy it changes the whole row instead:

```
Matrix[0][1].append(1)
```

output:

```
[[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```

but i wanted it to work like this:

```
[[[], [1], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: shouldn't be :
Matrix[0][1] = [1]

Comment: @j1-lee it looks like im already using a solution from there

Comment: @Marya yeah that works, but im curious why cant i use append

Comment: @schoolboychik No you're not. You still have `[[]] * 5`. Try `Matrix = [[[] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]`. Then you are good to use `append`.

Comment: append add the value to your matrix. You want to change the value. That's why you should not use the append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use loops inside and outside the list of lists to avoid creating copies.

```
Matrix = [[[] for _ in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

print(Matrix)
[[[], [1], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```